# c++ ctor template / common function (template restrict iterator) can't compile

Tags: c++11, templates

I'm writing a class, like std::vector can be construct by n value or iterator [first, last), example code like below:

```
template<typename T>
class Test1{
public:
    Test1(size_t n, const T& v){
        data_ = new T[n];
        for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++n){
            data_[i] = v;
        }
    }

    template<typename Iterator>
    Test1(Iterator first, Iterator last){
        size_t n = std::distance(first, last);
        data_ = new T[n];
        while(first != last){
            *data_++ = *first++;
        }
    }

    Test1(){
        if(nullptr != data_){
            delete[] data_;
            data_ = nullptr;
        }
    }

    T* data_;
};
```

usage:

```
Test1<int> t1(2, 0);

std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};
Test1<int> t2(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

but compile error:

```
...
In instantiation of Test1<T>::Test1(Iterator, Iterator) [with Iterator = int; T = int]
error: invalid type argument of unary
...
```

so my question is how to realize the both function, why template can't be compile and how to change it(restrict iterator type)?

A  method no need to check iterator, also can solve this:

```
template<typename Iterator, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<Iterator>::value, int>::type = 0>
Test1(Iterator first, Iterator last){ // integral can't use this function
    cout << "using first last" << endl;
    size_t n = std::distance(first, last);
    data_ = new T[n];
    while(first != last){
        *data_++ = *first++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use tag dispatching technique to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't compile because `t1` is trying to invoke the iterator constructor.

## C++20

The simplest way to solve this is simply using the C++20 concept `std::input_iterator`, like so:

```cpp
template<std::input_iterator Iterator>
Test1(Iterator first, Iterator last){
    size_t n = std::distance(first, last);
    data_ = new T[n];
    while(first != last){
        *data_++ = *first++;
    }
}
```

Additionally you will need to remove the invalid attempt to initialize the pointer (`data_(n, v)`) and increment `i` instead of `n` in the n value constructor.

## C++11

First we'll need a little extra utility:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_iterator {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, decltype(*std::declval<T>()++, void())> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};
```

This custom type trait uses SFINAE to check if the provided type can be incremented and dereferenced (the same way you're doing in your code).

You can use it like this:

```cpp
template<typename Iterator, typename std::enable_if<is_iterator<Iterator>::value, bool>::type = true>
Test1(Iterator first, Iterator last){
    size_t n = std::distance(first, last);
    data_ = new T[n];
    while(first != last){
        *data_++ = *first++;
    }
}
```

Comment: how about c++11

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a C++11 solution, it's a lot more ugly, but gets the job done just as well. (You removed the wrong `data` initialization, but you're still incrementing `n` rather than `i` in the other constructor. :)